# Find OpenCV sourcefile for RANSAC

Tags: opencv

I have trouble to find the RANSAC (findHomography() in calib3d.hpp) sourcecode file (.cpp) in the opencv folder. Does anyone know where the source code is? 
Is there in common and easy way to determine where the source code of a specific function in the OpenCV folder is? or do i need to look trough every file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source code for the function `findHomography()` - https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp#L319

**Q:**

> Is there in common and easy way to determine where the source code of
>   a specific function in the OpenCV folder is? or do i need to look
>   trough every file?

**A:**

Google is an extremely powerful tool, I tend to just Google the function I am looking for followed by "opencv github", if I can't find it by doing that I crawl through the source code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can search the GitHub repo, which will look inside every file. A search for `cv::findHomography` yields the provided link as one of the first few hits.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks for pointing that out. Drian if this answers your question please mark it answered.